# Dropwizard/Jersey resource - @JsonView and annotated Guice method interceptor

Tags: jersey, jackson, dropwizard

I'm trying to get my JSON views applied to the response of a resource. But the views never seem to be applied. ie all fields are returned within the JSON.

Here is my resource. The debug statement logs the correct JSON ie with the view applied, so I know the model object and annotations are correct.

```
@GET @Path("events")
@JsonView(Events.PresentationView.class)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Metrics
public Events getEvents() throws JsonProcessingException {

    Events events = eventsWebService.getAllEvents();
    LOG.debug("JSON: {}", objectMapper.writerWithView(Events.PresentationView.class).writeValueAsString(events));

    return events;
}
```

The object mapper used within above is the same one configured within the dropwizard environment.

Is there anything that needs to be done within the dropwizard config to enable the use of Jackson JSON views?

Thanks in advance

Update.
Updated code snippet to show the additional annotation, which is used to create a Guice method interceptor that records metrics. This is the cause of the problem. Remove it and works as expected.

With reference to this bug: https://github.com/google/guice/issues/101 
and debugging the Jackson and Jersey code. It seems that this method:
`com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.cfg.EndpointConfigBase.addAnnotation(Class<? extends Annotation>, Annotation, boolean)`
is never called when the metrics annotation is present.

This is because the method: `org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext, MessageBodyWriter)` doesn't find any annotations.

So back to the referenced bug. CGLib will make a proxy sub class of the resource where the annotations are not copied. Therefore the JsonView annotation is never found and hence not applied.

Above is not a solution, but at least an explanation.

Comment: your objectmapper does not know anything about your view. Do you have only 1 view or multiple ones? This sounds like a custom messageBodyWriter + annotation that creates the correct view for you

Comment: The view is provided within the annotation @JsonView.  Not seen the need for a custom message body writer in other examples, if so, then what is the annotation for?

Comment: you are right, i just wrote up an example and DW does this out of the box. What version are you on. Please provide a minimal standalone example of your problem as I can not reproduce it

Comment: Thanks for responding! Am using DW 1.0.0,  Jackson 2.8.2.  Will create a minimal app and see what happens.

Comment: That is really odd. My standalone that I just wrote up uses 1.0.0 DW and just works. You are right that you do not need anything for that. It seems something else in your application is messing with your serialisation

Comment: Thanks for your time on this. I created a minimal application and everything worked. With a bit of playing, it turns out it is a clash with an annotation on the resource (not shown above), which we use to add in some Statsd metrics using a Guice method interceptor. Removing the annotation fixes the problem. Will look into this further and report back.